# How to read a particular part of file in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have a file which has the following data

> !
>
> multiply 4 and 5
>
> multiply 5 and 6
>
> !
>
> add 3 to 4
>
> add 8 to 4
>
> !
>
> sub 3 from 6
>
> sub 9 from 5
>
> !
>
> !
>
> div 6 by 2
>
> div 8 by 1

I want to read only add commands from the file.

Using lookup plugin I was able to read the data of the entire file.

But I don't know how to read only the specific add commands from the file

Here's the code that I've written.

```
---
 - name: Extracting the Add commands from the File
   hosts: 127.0.0.1
   connection: local

   vars:
           contents: "{{lookup('file', 'file1.txt')}}"

   tasks:
           - name: Printing the Add commands of the File
             debug:
                     var: contents
```

I am stuck at this point.Could anyone help me out of how to read the specific part of a file in ansible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [with_lines](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/lines.html#lines-read-lines-from-command). The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_data_file: "{{ playbook_dir }}/data.txt"
    my_commands: []
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_commands: "{{ my_commands + [ item ] }}"
      with_lines: "cat {{ my_data_file }}"
      when: item is search('^add')
    - debug:
        var: my_commands
```

gives

```
"my_commands": [
    "add 3 to 4", 
    "add 8 to 4"
]
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. with_lines breaks the output("my_data_files" content) into lines and for each item the conditional when statement is run if the condition is passed that particular item will be added  to the my_commands list

Comment: I have another question I want to do the same task for another file and compare the outputs(both the output lists). Instead of writing the same task again with different variable(my_commands_2) Is there any way to write a single task and call it multiple times one for one file(let's say data1.txt) and one for another file(let's say data2.txt) and then compare the results.