# Error while accessing variables in vars file in a role

Tags: ansible

As a follow up to this question [How to read a particular part of file in ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56562112/how-to-read-a-particular-part-of-file-in-ansible). I am trying to do the same but by using roles. The variables are stored in vars files

Here is the vars/main.yml file in the role

```
add:
    commands: []
sub:
    commands: []
multiply: 
    commands: []
div:
    commands: []
```

Here's the code in tasks/main.yml file

```
 - name: Getting the Add Commands
   set_fact:
            add.commands: "{{add.commands + [ item ]}}"
   with_lines: "cat {{ {{playbook_dir}}/testing/files/data.txt }}"
   when: item is search('^add')
 - debug:
        var: add.commands
- name: Getting the Sub Commands
   set_fact:
            sub.commands: "{{sub.commands + [ item ]}}"
   with_lines: "cat {{ {{playbook_dir}}/testing/files/data.txt }}"
   when: item is search('^sub')
 - debug:
        var: sub.commands
- name: Getting the Multiply Commands
   set_fact:
            multiply.commands: "{{multiply.commands + [ item ]}}"
   with_lines: "cat {{ {{playbook_dir}}/testing/files/data.txt }}"
   when: item is search('^multiply')
 - debug:
        var: multiply.commands
- name: Getting the Div Commands
   set_fact:
            div.commands: "{{div.commands + [ item ]}}"
   with_lines: "cat {{ {{playbook_dir}}/testing/files/data.txt }}"
   when: item is search('^div')
 - debug:
        var: div.commands
```

Code to execute the role
testing.yml

```
 - name: Main Program
   hosts: localhost
   roles:
          - testing
```

I thought that I would get the add commands for add.commands and similarly for others but I am getting the following error

```
"msg": "The variable name 'add.commands' is not valid. Variables must start with a letter or underscore character, and contain only letters, numbers and underscores."
```

Can anyone tell me how to troubleshoot this error and why it happened in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

This is as expected and the error clearly states that.

Also as per ansible,

> Variable names should be letters, numbers, and underscores. Variables
>   should always start with a letter.

So `.` can't be part of the variable name.

Comment: Then Could you tell me how to access the commands variable of the 'add'.I tried using add['commands'] but it is giving me the same error